# blogdown indentation for TOML tables - in particular the default `config.toml` file

Tags: r, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown, toml

```
[params]
    description = "A website built through Hugo and blogdown."

    # options for highlight.js (version, additional languages, and theme)
    highlightjsVersion = "9.12.0"
    highlightjsCDN = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs"
    highlightjsLang = ["r", "yaml"]
    highlightjsTheme = "github"

    MathJaxCDN = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs"
    MathJaxVersion = "2.7.5"

    [params.logo]  # why is this indented?
    url = "logo.png"
    width = 50
    height = 50
    alt = "Logo"
```

The trailing end of the blogdown default `config.toml` file for the default `hugo-lithium` theme is shown above. I'm confused by the indentation of the `[params.logo]` table, five lines from the end of the file.

Shouldn't this `[params.logo]` table be non-indented? Why do I indent this `[params.logo]` table? Is it because it's a subset, and falls under the umbrella of the `[params]` table?

I can't find an explanation in [blogdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/configuration.html)'s book, although it may be there and I missed it. I can't imagine the default files are wrong.

```
[params]
    description = "A website built through Hugo and blogdown."

    # options for highlight.js (version, additional languages, and theme)
    highlightjsVersion = "9.12.0"
    highlightjsCDN = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs"
    highlightjsLang = ["r", "yaml"]
    highlightjsTheme = "github"

    MathJaxCDN = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs"
    MathJaxVersion = "2.7.5"

[params.logo]  # shouldn't it be non-indented?
    url = "logo.png"
    width = 50
    height = 50
    alt = "Logo"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indenting doesn't matter - see [the toml spec](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml)

In this case, it makes sense as a visual clue to the reader. `params.logo` is "under" params - the key `logo` is assigned a table as a value.